# Ruby Environment Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew

I can't seem to figure out what is going on with my Homebrew/Ruby environment on my Mac.

Here is my current output/state

```
$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
The current contents of /usr/local are bin CODEOFCONDUCT.md etc Library LICENSE.txt mysql mysql-5.7.11-osx10.9-x86_64 README.md share var .git .github .gitignore
$ brew doctor
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 172: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 172: exec: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: cannot execute: No such file or directory
$ brew update
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 172: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 172: exec: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: cannot execute: No such file or directory
$ brew list
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 172: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 172: exec: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: cannot execute: No such file or directory
$ brew install rbenv ruby-build
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 172: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 172: exec: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling Homebrew, which worked fine, but still the same situation when I complete.

I opened up `usr/local/Library/brew.sh` and found the following:

```
if [[ -z "$HOMEBREW_RUBY_PATH" ]]
then
  if [[ -n "$HOMEBREW_OSX" ]]
  then
HOMEBREW_RUBY_PATH="/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby"
  else
    HOMEBREW_RUBY_PATH="$(which ruby)"
  fi
fi
```

I tried replacing it with

```
if [[ -z "$HOMEBREW_RUBY_PATH" ]]
then
  if [[ -n "$HOMEBREW_OSX" ]]
  then
    HOMEBREW_RUBY_PATH="$(which ruby)"
  else
    HOMEBREW_RUBY_PATH="$(which ruby)"
  fi
fi
```

Then went to terminal:

```
$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Your Homebrew is outdated.
You haven't updated for at least 24 hours. This is a long time in brewland!
To update Homebrew, run `brew update`.
$ brew update
To restore the stashed changes to /usr/local run:
  'cd /usr/local && git stash pop'
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 174: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 174: exec: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

How do I get Ruby & Homebrew installed?

Comment: What is the output of `ruby -v`? Are you able to confirm that some ruby is installed on your system?

Comment: Your system Ruby should be found at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby`, but it isn't. Did you delete it? Since homebrew needs Ruby to work, I would suggest to install [Ruby first](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/). Then fix homebrew when you have at least one working Ruby version on your machine.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann, it seems that those instructions still want me to use Homebrew. Any other options?

Comment: what is the output of `which ruby` ? or does there `/usr/bin/ruby` exist? If ruby still exists somewhere else, I think you can temporally replace `HOMEBREW_RUBY_PATH` with an existing ruby binary path in `/usr/local/Library/brew.sh` to make Homebrew work and install Ruby in those instructions.

Comment: `which ruby` returns `/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: @5t111111 I updated the question.